# Checking intersection between two Path2D's

Tags: java, path, collision-detection, intersection, bounds

I have two Path2D objects in my game, one for the player and one for a tentacle that one of the bosses will have. I need to use Path2D because I want the bound to rotate together with the player/tentacle so that you can't get hit by it if you stand 5 pixels beside it. The problem with this is that I can't use `playerPath.intersects(tentaclPath)` because a Path2D can only check intersection with rectangles, this is a problem because it defeats the purpose of using Path2D's in my game. How would I be able to check if they intersect without transferring one of the paths to a rectangle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure your tentacle and player are closed paths.  (If not, they will be implicitly closed, and you will get tentacle hits when you don't think you should.)
2. Use the Area class to compute the intersection and see if it is empty

(Approximate code)

```
import java.awt.geom.Area;
...
boolean playerHitByTentacle(Tentacle t, Player p) {
    Area player = new Area(p.getPath2D());
    Area tentacle = new Area(t.getPath2D());
    player.intersect(tentacle);
    return !player.isEmpty();
}
```